# Angular - Reactive Forms subscribe to all forms passed to child component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm struggling with an issue and I cannot find a simple solution for this. This is a case with reactive forms in Angular.

I need to create a parent component, where I can add by clicking on the button some columns. Each column should have it's own instances of 2 controls: name and surname.

I've created a child component in which I'm passing a FormGroup where I have 2 FormControls for name and surname. In this case, I'm able to represent those 2 FormControls in my child component.

I would like to subscribe to all of these forms (or to 1 form if there is only 1 column added) in my parent component, and get all data from all of these forms (also check if all forms are valid).

With my current problem, it looks like I need to loop for each FormGroup passed to child component, and subscribe to it. Is there a way to simply subscribe to the Form as "whole", no matter how many forms we have? Is there a better solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

This is the code how I'm creating new FormGroup once I'm adding a new column:

```
    addNewColumn() {
       const group = new FormGroup({
         name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
         surname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
       });

        this.columns.push({
            formGroup: group
        });
    }
```

In parent component html I'm passing these columns in *ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let column of columns;>
  <child-component-column [columnForm]="column"></child-component-column>
</div>
```

In child component I'm taking this columnForm and represents the inputs like this:

```
<div [formGroup]="columnForm.formGroup">
  <ng-container>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input id="column-name" 
             matInput 
             type="text"
             maxLengthValue="20"
             formControlName="name" />     
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="m-t-10">
       <input id="column-surname" 
              matInput 
              formControlName="surname" />
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why do you need this? What is the reason you need to subscribe to all child forms? Do you know you can subscribe to the parent form valueChanges as well?

Comment: That's what I want to avoid - subscribing to all child forms. I would like to subscribe to the whole form in parent component, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: I understood that, but what is the reason? E.g. do you want to perform an action whenever the form value changes?

Comment: The reason is, I would like to get all data from all forms from all columns and send them via API. I also need to check the validation for all of these inputs. Simply, I would like to treat all inputs (form controls) from all columns as one Form to which I can subscribe to achieve this. I've read also about form array, but I'm not sure how to use it in my case.

Comment: I see, please checkout my answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray). You can do this, for example as follows:

In the parent component TS:

```
public form = new FormGroup({
    people: new FormArray<any>([])
});

get peopleArray(): FormArray<any> {
    return this.form.controls.people as FormArray<any>;
}
```

To add a new person:

```
addPerson(): void {
   const group = new FormGroup({
       name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
       surname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
   });
   this.peopleArray.push(group);
}
```

In parent component HTML:

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="people" *ngFor="let person of peopleArray.controls">
        <child-component-column [columnForm]="person"></child-component-column>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you do it this way, you can simply access the form valid state / form value from the parent component.

```
// To get value
const formValue = this.form.value;
const people = formValue.people;

// To see if form is valid (including all people)
const valid = this.form.valid;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. FormArray is exactly what I needed! Thanks for your help!